# How to maximize the width of middle cell of linear layout in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout that's horizontal. It has three textviews in it. How can I set it so that the left and right widths are wrapping contents, but the center cell width is fully maximized, and the textview is left aligned in it? I want to create this in only java.

This is what I have so far, but the middle cell is not being maximized...
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

```
    LinearLayout titleLL = new LinearLayout(this);
    titleLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView num = new TextView(this);
    num.setText(String.format("%d", index+1));
    num.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    num.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.title_numbering);
    num.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.title_numbering_background);

    TextView name = new TextView(this);
    name.setText(task.name);
    name.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 10);
    name.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.title);

    TextView edit = new TextView(this);
    edit.setText("Edit");

    titleLL.addView(num);
    titleLL.addView(name);
    titleLL.addView(edit);
```

Comment: You could set weight for the textviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use weight when you add your middle textview:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
titleLL.addView(name, params);
```